# Dockerfile fast api running port dynamically

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, fastapi

I have a Dockerfile that looks like this

```
# Pull base image
FROM python:3.9.2-slim-buster

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get -y install gcc \
  && apt-get -y install g++ \
  && apt-get -y install unixodbc unixodbc-dev \
  && apt-get clean


# Set environment varibles
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /code/

# Install dependencies
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip3 install --requirement /code/requirements.txt


COPY ./start.sh /start.sh


COPY . /code/



CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port $PORT"]
```

The port seems to be coming up w/ escaping ?

When I deploy the following docker in heroku it reads following

```
Starting process with command `uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port\ \21634`
```

There are slashes infront of port. Why?

Answer (score 0):

The spaces are because you have put it into one of the elements of the list given to `ENTRYPOINT`. If you compare it to your other entries, there's a new element for each term in the command, while you have two terms inside the one where you have `$PORT` - this means that it's being processed as a single parameter, and in that case Docker (or an alternative container runtime) needs to escape the spaces to build the command you're asking for.

Replace it with separate elements instead:

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "$PORT"]
```

Comment: That did not get rid of the escape. I still see the following
``uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port \48636``

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same struggle. One working solution was using alternative way of writting the CMD without brackets - and it works.

```
CMD uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

It looks weird in logs, but works indeed.
[image]

```
(truncated log)
Starting process with command `/bin/sh -c uvicorn\ main:app\ --host\ 0.0.0.0\ --port\ \7238`
Started server process [4]
Waiting for application startup.
Application startup complete.
Uvicorn running on http://0.0.0.0:7238 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```